# Turn off audio in all pages inside my entire website with JS

Tags: javascript, audio

So inside my website I have 4 pages, index and the others. On all pages, I have the menu nav and if the user hovers on an anchor inside the menu, a sound is played. I found this that could be annoying so I made a button which turn sound off on click, but it only turns sound off on the current page ( I mean I knew this from the beginning ). Is there any method that I can use to turn off the audio on the first click on my entire website so the user doesn't have to click the audio off button every single time? Is it possible with JS? What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: You could use server-side PHP and loop through all pages, and echo a mute script.

Answer (score 0):

On button click, save a flag in `localStorage`, eg:

```
button.onclick = () => {
  localStorage.mute = 1 - Number(localStorage.mute);
  // this will result in `.mute` being either '0' or '1' (strings)
  // perform mute operation too, if a sound is currently playing, if you want
};
```

Then, in your hover listener, return immediately if `.mute` is `1`:

```
.onhover = () => {
  if (localStorage.mute === '1') {
    return;
  }
  // play sound
};
```

If you only want the mute button to persist for the current session (tab lifetime), use `sessionStorage` instead.